# Adding a custom navigation drawer action bar icon

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I've implemented a navigation drawer, and it has the standard 3 lines going across. 
I've been looking around for methods to change that icon, but I haven't found much luck. I really only want to make the lines more spaced out and longer (like in the playstore).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to change the

[image: Drawer icon] icon

There is a [Navigation Drawer Indicator Generator](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-nav-drawer-indicator.html) in the Android Asset Studio.

The icon is available for [download](http://developer.android.com/downloads/design/Android_Design_Icons_20130926.zip) in the Android training lesson [Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ActionBarIcon).

As far as I can tell, you can follow that tutorial and swap in whatever icon you'd like.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that in the tutorial. I went straight to googling and apparently I fail at that too.

Comment: actually, to imitate the one in the playstore I needed to set the correct action bar style. I'm sure there's a way to define my own to make the nav icon not have a left padding/margin but didn't didn't figure that part out. Thanks for your help!